# Forward Lookup Zone missing from SBS2003 SP2

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-sbs-2003

We have a new customer running SBS 2003 SP2 (standalone) whose AD not working.  At first glance it looks like the cause is the fact that the AD integrated forward lookup zone is missing, so directory services won't start.  Because Directory Services won't start I am unable to readd or restore the AD integrated zone.

Any suggestions on a fix?

Edit:

Would this re add the zone?

Ntsdutil

Authoritative restore

Restore subtree “dc=DeletedZone.com,cn=MicrosoftDNS,dc=forestDNSZones,dc=contoso,dc=com”

Comment: Looking forward to an answer to this.

Comment: Look through the event log and tell us any pertinent errors that are there. Event IDs can be a big help.

Comment: Event 4015 is the main one I see and seems to have started them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this solution?

1. Start Add or Remove Programs->Add/Remove Windows Components.
2. Double click on Networking Services and then uncheck DNS.
3. Click Next to finish the un-installation.
4. Find and remove the following files:

%systemroot%\Windows\System32\DNS\Cache.dns

%systemroot%\Windows\System32\Config\Netlogon.dns

%systemroot%\Windows\System32\Config\Netlogon.dnb

5. Reinstall DNS.
6. Restart the server and test this issue.

There is also this article from MS that sound as if it applies:

[MS Tech Article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=310568)